# How to make size output for array the same from inside function compared to main?

Tags: c++, arrays, scope

`sizeof(arr)` is returning different values from inside `main` and in `arr_size`. I expect the array to have all the same properties, I tested that the array isn't completely ruined by accessing a value which worked in all scopes, so I'm at a loss.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void arr_size(std::string* arr_) {
    std::cout << sizeof(arr_) << std::endl; // 8
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string arr[100] = {};
    arr[0] = "iiiiiiiiiiiiiii";

    arr_size(arr);

    std::cout << sizeof(arr) << std::endl; // 3200
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

As it shows: the `sizeof()` the array from within `arr_size` is `8`, while the expected size given from within `main` is `3200`.

Edit, dereferencing `arr_` returns the size of std::string, which I would also like to understand.

Comment: When your expectations don't match your observation usually your expectations were wrong and it's worth taking a look at [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) to check what a class/function/keyword actually does.

Comment: arrays can decay to pointers, but arrays are not pointers

Comment: @idclev463035818 Why is it that de-referencing the array in the function will give the size of a single element?

Comment: `sizeof(arr_)` is not dereferencing the array. It is the same as `sizeof(std::string*)`. `arr_` is a pointer to a string. `arr` in `main` is a `std::string[100]`, you need to understand that those are different types.

Comment: or maybe you were refering to code that isnt included in your post. `sizeof( *arr_)` is the same as `sizeof ( std::string)` because `*arr_` is `std::string`

Comment: It's very unintuitive that de referencing a pointer gives different properties than the original object, but I guess it makes sense. Interested in solutions which are more elegant than adding a function parameter if that's even possible in c++.

Comment: @user7778287 You may want to pass a `std::array<std::string,100> const&`. Or, if you want to stick to your array, pass it as reference: `template <typename T, std::size_t N> void arr_size(T const (&arr)[N]) { /* ... */ }`